# How do I alter the value being updated in a ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, updating

I can't seem to find an answer to this, maybe I'm not using the correct terminology.

I have a ListView that is editable, I want it so that if a user clicks on Edit and then Update, that the field is updated with the value from another textbox, not the field they are editing.

The reason for this is that I have a Colour Picker that alters the value of a textbox, when they click Update I want this value to be the updated value.

I guess I utilise the ItemUpdating event, but I don't have much in the way of code because I'm pretty lost. I have this so far:

```
protected void ListView2ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedItem = ListView2.Items[ListView2.EditIndex];

// I have no idea what to put here
 something = ColourChosen.Value;
}
```

Here is an image that I hope will make what I'm trying to do a little more understandable:

[image: ListView2]

If any one could point me in the right direction of any examples, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does colorpicker alter the value, is it validating the ListView2 value and changing its color, based on some rules?

Comment: I have code at the moment where the colour picker alters the value of a textbox. I have a button to add this value to the listview, the listview displays the color by this code: <tr style="background-color:#<%# Eval("PlotColour1") %>;">. So adding a value isn't an issue, it's the editing of them I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: I think you may want to use ListView2_Validating to do this, by check the value of the added value to set the color in the ListView.

Comment: Hold on. Am I doing this completely the wrong way round? Should I be updating my database table instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer my initial question this does what I want to happen.

What I should be doing is altering the database that ListView is attached to.

I use this code:

```
protected void ListView2ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  using (var myEntities = new i96X_utilEntities())
  {
    var myPlotColour = (from plotC in myEntities.PlotColours
                        where plotC.ID == selectedID
                        select plotC).Single();
    myPlotColour.PlotColour1 = ColourChosen.Value;
    myEntities.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

So, even though I have no idea how to intercept a field being updated in a ListView, in this example I don't need to.